# CKEditor 4 uses separate span tags for each formatting action

Tags: ckeditor

I've been searching through a large number of CKEditor posts and have yet to find a targeted answer to this question. I know CKEditor is very configurable (which I haven't leveraged yet.)

For every formatting action performed, CKEditor wraps it in a separate span tag. So if I 1) change the font to Arial 2) change the size to 36px 3) change the color, I end up with this HTML which seems unnecessarily verbose.

```
<p><span style="color:#DAA520"><span style="font-size:36px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Hi</span></span></span></p>
```

I would rather it just did something like `<p style="..styles list">Hi</p>`

**My question**: Is this configurable (and how), and/or is there a rationale for them doing it this way where I should just accept the behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly seems like a relatively clean means of implementation on CK Editor's part, and would help it avoid conflicting logic for different styles applied to dissimilar spans.

If you as the user want consistent differences with multiple variables like size, color, or font, you should really be using classes, I would think. A WYSIWYG editor like CK is designed to implement HTML code that is readable, not pretty. If you want more elegant code, you probably need to write it yourself.

Since other adaptations from WYSIWYG editors/ word processors generate obscene looking code, e.g. Microsoft Word/ Outlook, or Adobe's new CSS from layout feature, this span output isn't actually too bad.

Comment: As a CKEditor core dev I can only add that you're right :) It'd be extremely tricky to merge elements by name having the styles list still configurable and the implementation maintainable and stable for great majority of cases.